# problem in calculating lambda with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I need to convert the value of the 'Amount' field to dollar, based on the value of another 'Currency' field, but I don't understand why the value of the first record is repeated to me throughout the dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
def calculo_dolar_2(data):
  valor = (data*1000)/float(precio_dolar)
  return valor

df_conversion_dolar_2['ED'] = df_conversion_dolar_2['Currency'].apply(lambda x: ( df_conversion_dolar_2['Amount'].apply(calculo_dolar_2)) if x=='$$' else df_conversion_dolar_2['Amount'])

df_conversion_dolar_2
```

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vULoN.png)

I am trying in this other way, but without success:

```html
precio_dolar = 800
def calculo_dolar_3(data):
  if data == '$$':
    valor = (df_conversion_dolar_2['Amount']*1000)/float(precio_dolar)
  else:
    valor = df_conversion_dolar_2['Amount']
  return valor

df_conversion_dolar_2['ED'] = df_conversion_dolar_2['Currency'].apply(lambda x: df_conversion_dolar_2['Amount'].apply(calculo_dolar_3))

df_conversion_dolar_2
```

What is it due to?

Comment: Your code makes no sense, can you break it down into small steps ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please see these guidelines on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and especially the sections on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [why not to post a picture of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: @SyKer ready, its is understand now? thanks!!

Comment: It's getting better.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the code but this is how I would do it;

```
# make your code clear (what is 2?) 
df = df_conversion_dolar_2

precio_dolar = 800

# first, let's make a boolean selector 
dolar_select = df['Currency'] == '$$$'

# Selecting dollar rows at the column Amount is as follow:
# This line is only to show you what happens and is not 
# needed in your final code
df.loc[dolar_select, 'Amount'] 

# Anyway, now we apply your function to the selected data:
df['ED'] = df.loc[dolar_select, 'Amount'].map(lambda x: (x*1000)/float(precio_dolar))

# Finally, fill the NaN values in your dataframe (the non selected rows)
df.loc[df['ED'].isna(), 'ED'] = df['Amount']
```

Comment: Great!!, I will test the logic you comment and I'll be back in a while, thank you very much!!

Comment: No problem, you might get an error with values not same length. The important concept here is the boolean selector and df.loc[selector, 'column']

Comment: Thanks @Sy Ker !! yesterday I went to rest and today I already had everything processed in my head, thanks for the support ;)

 I want score you, but no is possible because i'm newbie in Stackoverflow, but i will do it soon!!

Comment: by the way, thank you very much for the explanation, it helps me a lot for my training :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do can be accomplished like so

```
def calculo_dolar_2(data):
  valor = (data*1000)/float(precio_dolar)
  return valor

df_conversion_dolar_2['ED'] = df_conversion_dolar_2.apply(lambda x: calculo_dolar_2(x['Amount']) if x['Currency']=='$$' else x['Amount'])
```

Comment: thanks you very much @Eeshaan, you logic is the right, but i add "axis=1" in the end code and this work. thanks you very much. 

I want score you, but no is possible because i'm newbie in Stackoverflow, but i will do it soon!! ;)

Comment: Yes please xD. Even I'm a newbie, and an upvote and answer acceptation can really help me out.